# When i hide one item (anyone) in checkout_index_index.xml payment method doesn't work , Magento 2

Tags: magento2

When  I hide one item (anyone) in `checkout_index_index.xml` **payment method** doesn't work, thanks for help.

For example.

```
<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
   <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code</item>
   <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
   <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">                                                                   
       <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
   </item>
</item>
```

and result:
[image]

Comment: Show your cart_index_index.xml.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a correction, checkout_index_index.xml no cart_index_index

Comment: I can't show a very long file, I overwrite module-checkout / frontend / layout / checkout_index_index.xml in my custom theme and make changes there, except <item name = "visible" xsi: type = "boolean"> false </ Item>  i don't change nothing  .

Comment: It may be because you are trying to hide a required field.

Comment: Anshu Mishra  if I hide the company's field, which is optional, the problem doesn't disappear

Comment: try this

<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
</item>